# How to manage huge number of vegetation positions across the world

Tags: procedural-generation

How to manage positions of huge number of vegetation (grass in particular) in games?
Do the positions have to be memorized or do they have to be generated on the fly? If so, can the grass always have the same positions?

I see that noise can be used to generate positions but I'm not sure how to manage them afterwards.

Also, if you have resources on this subject, I would be glad to know them.

Comment: _"Do the positions have to be memorized or do they have to be generated on the fly? If so, can the grass always have the same positions?"_ Only you can answer those questions. What are the requirements of your game regarding this?

Comment: We talked about this in [chat] just recently - [see the start of the thread here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59380157#59380157). It includes links to a couple of GDC talks about [distributing vegetation in Horizon Zero Dawn](https://gdcvault.com/play/1024120/GPU-Based-Run-Time-Procedural) and [working with noise functions](https://gdcvault.com/play/1024365/Math-for-Game-Programmers-Noise).

Comment: Thank you both, I'm seeing the conferences right now. 
My requirement is a top down game, with huge areas (say 100x100km for the example). I realize that even in memory I wouldn't have the space to store all that grass.